# Fog error: undefined method `available?' for MoudleName:Module

Tags: ruby, fog

I have created new module for fog and its working well but, when I am trying to run tests using command

`export FOG_MOCK=true && bundle exec shindont` getting below error

> /fog/lib/fog/bin.rb:6:in block in available_providers': undefined method available?' for MoudleName:Module (NoMethodError)

I have not written any test for the new module.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by adding  `require 'module name'` in `fog/lib/fog/bin.rb`